# How does the retaining mechanism work on USB-C, and what will wear out?

Tags: usb, cable, charging, usb-c

I’ve looked for a good crossection of the mechanical elelements of a usb-c connector, and I can’t find a good one.

I’m curious how the retaining mechanism (the thing that makes it “click” in to place) works.

Is it located on the connector, or the port?

How is it likely to fail, and in what way?

How many cycles is a standard cable and port rated for?

For context:

I have a USB-C cable that I quite like (right angle, nylon braided, good length) and it has a very tight fit, with a very satisfying “click”.

However I’m concerned that this tight fitting cable might cause my charging ports to wear out faster, or to overtime fit less snugly around cables that already lacked that firm “click”. In other words, I’m worried about this “tight” cable stretching out the retaining mechanism and me winding up with a sloppy fitting connection.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I am no expert on the topic. I was wondering the same thing as you and ended up looking it up in the specification.

The tab in the receptacle features two notches on either sides. The plug has matching springy metal latches which lock onto those tabs from the sides.

It says it all on [page 39 of the specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf)

> Retention of the cable assembly in the receptacle is achieved by the side-latches in the plug and features on the sides of the receptacle tongue.

There's a very clear drawing of the receptacle feature on page 42. I don't know if it is legal to screenshot the drawing so I'll let you look it up.

In lieu of proper drawings, here are some pictures of actual connectors where I attempted to mark the features:

[front view of the receptacle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VgYp.jpg)
[another view of a receptacle from the back through a hole in the shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBhSL.jpg)
[latch inside the plug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq70c.jpg)

Funny thing, docking stations are exempt of this requirement, which means that a docking station might not "click" like a regular cable does.